# how to get an output in R, when we have dynamic UI which is dependent on input?

Tags: r, shiny, purrr

Basically, I am creating an App which will have dynamic input. The user will enter the values inside the textInput and then the data will be automatically stored in the datatable.

For Example : Lets say I have to enter name of **Items** and **Quantity** I bought from store just onces. The number of items are going to vary. so I need to have dynamic input and also a provision to store it in data format.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

numericInput("n", "Number of items", value = 5, min = 1),

uiOutput("col"),

textOutput("text"))

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
 
  item_names <- reactive(paste0("item", seq_len(input$n)))

  qty <- reactive(paste0("qty", seq_len(input$n))) 
 
  strr <- reactive(tribble(~item, ~qty, item_names(), qty())) 
 
  output$col<- renderUI({
    map2(strr(), ~textInput({..1}, "Item", ""),
               textInput({..2}, "Qty", ""))})

  output$text<- renderText({
  map_chr(item_names(), ~ input[[.x]])})  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I know the code is quite wrong.
Any direction or help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think for such usecases, it's easier to generate a table depending on the number of items, that the user then can fill out. It's possible for example with `rhandsontable`

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I think ```rhandsontable``` will work fine